# How can I stretch the google map on my page to fit the container horizontally in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I'm following this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-mean-apps-with-google-maps-part-i and the author decided to put google map on his page by writing:

```
<!-- Google Map -->
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div id="map" style="width:645px; height:645px"></div>
</div>
```

Now even though he put the map in the `col-md-7`, he assigned to it specific width and height, so this map does not get smaller on mobile devices or wider on panoramic monitors. Is there a way of removing the specific width and height and adjust it automatically so it fits the parent `<div class="container">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the map to grow to the width of its parent, `col-md-7`.

```
<!-- Google Map -->
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:645px"></div>
</div>
```

Or if you'd rather just use CSS you can leave the inline width the same and do this in your stylesheet:

```
#map{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick!, I will accept this answer as soon as I can :)